# WPF Converter not running when binding to the whole object and some properties has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I've reached my mental barier and not able to figure it out. I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I'm stuck. The code below is the minimal code required to see my problem but is far away from my production code.

**Setting:**
I have a WPF window with a **DataGrid** control that is **bound to a business object** that includes a **collection of assets**. For **every asset** I need to display a user control (SpecialButton) which **visibility** is determined based on **multiple properties of an asset object**. When I click on the button (*in my example I have an extra button that changes the properties for simplicity*) it changes a property of the underlying asset object which should make the control hidden.

**Problem**
I bind the user control attached property `ControlVisibility` to the whole asset object `{Binding .}`
`<local:SpecialButton x:Name="buttonOnEachRow"  ControlId="{Binding Id}"
  ControlVisibility="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>`
When I change a property of the Asset object `PropertyA`I expect the `MyConverter` should run and change the visibility value but it never happen.

**What I've tried**
I've tried so many things that I even don't remember. The most promising seems to be `MultipleBinding` but I was not able to figure out how to write the syntax for the `ControlVisibility` property. I tried some settings on the `DataGrid` control, changing the way how the `user control` is updated but no vail.
As a workaround, in my production code, I created a `fake` property that performs the logic that is currently in the converter and bind the `ControlVisibility` to the `fake` property. That works but I have a completely unrelated property in my asset object that is there just because I can't figure out the binding.

**The main WPF Window**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace MultiBindingProblem
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var sut = new BusinessObject() { Caption = "This is the parent object", Assets = new List<Asset>()};
            sut.Assets.Add(new Asset() { Name = "Asset 1", Id = 1 });
            sut.Assets.Add(new Asset() { Name = "Asset 2", Id = 2 });
            sut.Assets.Add(new Asset() { Name = "Asset 3", Id = 3 });
            this.DataContext = sut;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void BtnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void BtnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((BusinessObject)this.DataContext).Assets[0].PropertyA = true;
            //PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Assets"));            
        }
    }
}
```

XAML
The `btnChange` is here for simplicity. In my production code the SpecialButton will trigger the property update in my viewmodel

```
<Window x:Class="MultiBindingProblem.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiBindingProblem"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <Window.Resources>
            <local:TestConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
        </Window.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="100" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock x:Name="lblMainObject" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="25"
                       Text="{Binding Caption}" />
            <Button x:Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True" IsDefault="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="BtnCancel_Click" />
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgrData" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Assets, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action button" Width="100">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!--
                                Here I bind to the whole 'Asset' object to be able to determine if the button should be
                                visible based on multiple properties. But changing a propety doesn't raise the converter.
                                I tried use multiple bindings but I was not able to figure out the syntax
                                -->
                                <local:SpecialButton x:Name="buttonOnEachRow" 
                                                     ControlId="{Binding Id}"
                                                     ControlVisibility="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>

            <Button x:Name="btnChange" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Change visibility of the first button" Click="BtnChange_Click" />

        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

**The user control (SpecialButton)**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MultiBindingProblem
{
    public partial class SpecialButton : UserControl
    {
        public SpecialButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlIdProperty =
                                DependencyProperty.Register("ControlId", typeof(int),
                                typeof(SpecialButton));

        public int ControlId
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ControlIdProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ControlIdProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlVisibilityProperty =
                                DependencyProperty.Register("ControlVisibility", typeof(Visibility),
                                typeof(SpecialButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));

        public Visibility ControlVisibility
        {
            get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ControlVisibilityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ControlVisibilityProperty, value); }
        }

        private void btnSpecialButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"The id of the button: {((Button)sender).Tag.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="MultiBindingProblem.SpecialButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MultiBindingProblem"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="45" d:DesignWidth="80" 
             x:Name="parent">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=parent}">
            <Button x:Name="btnSpecialButton" Content="Click Me" Click="btnSpecialButton_Click"
                    Tag="{Binding ControlId}"   
                    Visibility="{Binding ControlVisibility}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**TestConverter**

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MultiBindingProblem
{
    public class TestConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var asset = value as Asset;
            if (asset == null) return Visibility.Hidden;
            return !(asset.PropertyA || asset.PropertyB) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**
Can I somehow use `Multibinding`?
Or
How to make the converter run when a single property has changed on the asset object?

Comment: "*When I change a property of the Asset object PropertyA I expect the MyConverter should run and change the visibility*" - that expectation is wrong. MultiBinding to a set of properties should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a MultiBinding with a multi-value converter like this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<local:SpecialButton ...>
    <local:SpecialButton.ControlVisibility>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}">
            <Binding Path="PropertyA"/>
            <Binding Path="PropertyB"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </local:SpecialButton.ControlVisibility>
</local:SpecialButton>
```

Your current converter implementation looks like it should return `Visible` if none of the input properties is `true`. An equivalent multi-value converter could be this:

```
public class MultiBooleanToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool any = values.Any(v => v is bool && (bool)v);

        return any ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Clemens. I knew it just needs something simple somewhere. I'm not really skilled in WPF so I was lost there and there. One day completely wasted, now I can go to bed :) Thank you again!